# Accusative with "gewohnt" and general patterns versus isolated locutions

Tags: grammatical-case, accusative

The basic story of the four grammatical cases might say that nominative is used in subjects and in predicate nominatives, accusative is used for objects of most verbs, some verbs take only dative objects, some take both dative and accusative objects, and there are four sorts of prepositions, some having accusative objects when motion toward something is indicated.

Then there are things like "Ich denke an **ihn**." versus "Was findest du an **ihm** gut?". With these, particular locutions must be learned, but maybe they're not just isolated cases but part of some pattern.

And then I came across the following: A sentence in a novel in English says "I'm not used to it." and a translation into German says "Ich bin **es** nicht gewohnt." I might have guessed that the dative case would be used here. Is this altogether isolated, or is it part of some pattern that would have enabled one to predict that the accusative would be used? If it's an isolated thing that must be learned separately from everything else, which other isolated instances exist?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you expected the dative to be used in *es gewohnt sein*?

Comment: Re the *an* thing: it’s just *Wechselpräpositionen* all over again. What are you finding good? something *on* or *near* him. In German *an,* a *Wechselpräposition*. Is the thing you find good moving towards him or resting at him? The second, so dative.

Comment: @Jan : But "Ich denke an ihn." does not involve motion toward him.

Comment: @DavidVogt : Accusative is used for direct objects of verbs. This doesn't seem at all like one of those.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Your thoughts are moving towards him because they are not originally on or near him.

Comment: @Jan : I've never thought of it in that way, and it doesn't seem like a plausible metaphor. Maybe German-speaking people think of it that way, but only because of that way of using the language.

Comment: @MichaelHardy No, we don’t really think about it at all. Like all things in language it’s a process of the cerebellum or somewhere equally deep down away from consciousness and it just happens. We just ‘get it right’—like native English speakers ‘just’ get the grammatical oddities of English ‘right’.

Comment: @Jan : But you _do_ think of it when you write comments like what you wrote above.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I look at the structure and reverse engineer a possible origin

Comment: Maybe the reason why I expected the dative is that the word "to" is used in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned the [valency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_(linguistics)) of verbs and prepositions in your question. Your question is about the valency of adjectives.

In the following examples, I have marked the adjectives in bold and their arguments in italics.

1. Adjectives with dative only:

   > *Ihm* ist **kalt/schlecht/langweilig**.
2. Adjectives with subject and genitive:

   > Mit 15 war *ich* *der Schule* **überdrüssig**.
   >   Sie staunten, als *sie* *des Bildes* **ansichtig** wurden.
   >   die *des Lateinischen* **mächtigen** *Schüler*
3. Adjectives with subject and dative:

   > *Überheblichkeit* schien *ihr* **fremd**.
   >   *Diese Tatsache* ist *mir* **bekannt**.
   >   das *ihnen* dabei **behilfliche** *Computerprogramm*
4. Adjectives with subject and a prepositional object:

   > *Sie* dürfen **stolz** *auf ihre Leistung* sein.
   >   eine *an Höhepunkten* **arme** *Partie*
5. Adjectives with subject and accusative:

   > *Sie* ist *den Ärger* **gewohnt**.
   >   *Ich* habe *den Streit* **satt**.

Group 2 seems like the biggest one. So for adjectives, the genitive might play the same role as the accusative for verbs as the default or at least most frequent oblique case.

In groups 3 and 4, the adjectives can sometimes be paired with a closely corresponding verb.

> Sie ähnelt ihrer Mutter. – *Sie* ist *ihrer Mutter* **ähnlich**.
>   Wir freuen uns über jeden Tipp. – *Wir* sind **froh** *über jeden Tipp*.

Note that *froh* used to take the genitive: *des Lebens nicht mehr froh werden*.

It it also worth mentioning that *es* used to be a genitive form that was later replaced by *sîn*. A standard Middle High German grammar* posits that in phrases such as *es leid sein*, *es* used to be a genitive that was later reinterpreted as an accusative. So group 5 is the youngest group and might still be growing, whereas group 2 might be getting smaller.

* Paul, Hermann: Mittelhochdeutsche Grammatik. 23. Aufl. von P. Wiehl und S. Grosse. Tübingen 1989.

Answer (score 2):

> Ich bin **den Ärger mit den Fällen** gewohnt. *(Akkusativ)*
>
> Der Ärger mit den Fällen bleibt **mir** treu. *(Dativ)*
>
> Ich werde **des Ärgers mit den Fällen** müde. *(Genitiv)*

*Gewohnt sein/bleiben*, *treu sein/bleiben*, *müde sein/bleiben/werden* and numerous other verb phrases are highly idiomatic and the cases used defy any logic. (Okay, the receiver→dative "rule" still applies for the *Treue*, but it's hard to wrap your mind around why it shouldn't apply to *Gewohnheit*. Answer: Because it's *Ich* who acts in the first example, not *der Ärger* as in the second. No clue about the third one. It must be genitive. No special reason.)

Comment: To avoid confusion we should say somewhere that *Fälle* is dative case, or use an example in singular where the case is more obvious.

Comment: These are actually not *verb phrases* that drive the case here, instead there are a number of *adjectives* that rule a certain case (most often genitive), a fact which is often overlooked in German grammar.